# Regexp not matching extension

Tags: java, regex

I want to find all files with certain extension in certain path. Example:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("/Users/*/*\\.png");
Matcher m = p.matcher("/Users/me/failed.png");
m.find()
```

this should result in true, however its false, so i tried to be more specific:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("/Users/*/[a-z]*\\.png");
Matcher m = p.matcher("/Users/me/failed.png");
m.find()
```

However everything is false, but the regexp should match the given input. Why is this resulting in false? Is there something about regexp i have missed? Thanks for help!

Comment: `*` doesn’t do what you think it does. Perhaps you are getting glob and regex confused. `*` means zero or more of the thing to the left. Neither regex allows `me/failed`.

Comment: @Biffen so why does /Users/*/* matches the string?

Comment: Which string, exactly, does `/Users/*/*` match?

Comment: @Biffen it matches "/Users/me/failed.png"

Comment: @Biffen oh, find() and matches() have different purpose, my bad, it does not matches it. Makes sense it find() something

Comment: _Within_ the string `/Users/me/failed.png` the regex `/Users/*/*` will match `/Users/`.